# Decidability of an Algebraic System in Real Numbers

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, decidability

Is there an algorithm to decide whether an algebraic system 
\begin{gathered}
  {f_1}({x_1}, \ldots ,{x_n}) = 0 \hfill \\
   \vdots  \hfill \\
  {f_m}({x_1}, \ldots ,{x_n}) = 0 \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}
where $f_1,\ldots,f_m$ are polynomials with given rational coefficients, has a solution in real numbers?

Comment: You need to be a little more precise. I assume the f's are polynomials: what are their coefficients? However, for the rationals, there is an algorithm. See, for example, here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_closed_field#Model_theory:_decidability_and_quantifier_elimination

Comment: See Tarski's work on the decidability of (real closed?) fields.  You need to be more specific about the system.  For example, it might be undecidable if a cosine term is there (in which case Tarski's work does not apply).

Comment: Also, I think James Cranch misspoke: for the reals (not rationals) and certain algebraic systems, there is a decision procedure.   The link James provided gives some detail.

Comment: Masked Avenger - from the point of view of algorithmics, one wants to know how those real numbers are specified. When I say "rationals", I assume they'll be specified as quotients of integers, and that's okay. For arbitrary reals I worry that they might come as strings of digits. Then there's not even an algorithm to tell if such a real is zero. Tarski's theorem requires that we know such facts about the reals we're given, and that's unreasonable from an algorithmic perspective.

Comment: While representation in machine language is important, especially from an algorithmic perspective, I'm afraid the statement regarding rationals contradicts work on Hilbert's tenth problem.  And further work (undecidability of Robinson's arithmetic) also suggest no decision procedure for such systems over the rationals.

Comment: Oh, that's a good point!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this follows from Tarski's theorem (1951) that the first order theory of real closed fields admits elimination of quantifiers. See also the [Tarski-Seidenberg theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%E2%80%93Seidenberg_theorem).

**P.S.** A consequence of these theorems is that if the given polynomial system has a solution in real numbers, then it also has a solution in real algebraic numbers.